# JavaScript loop to call a different function every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm (poorly) attempting to create a simple page which loops between a clock + date, current weather, 7-day weather forecast, news and calendar events. Each of these 'items' are called upon using functions.

For example; I've created functions like:

```
displayTime();      // Time + date using Moment.js
currentWeather();   // Current weather using Forecast.io        (AJAX call)
forecastWeather();  // Weekly forecast of the weather           (AJAX call)
latestNews();       // Latest headlines from RSS source/s       (AJAX call)
calendarEvents();   // Calendar events from iCloud calendars
```

They all work perfectly when I call them on their own; but on jQuery document ready I want to call the clock + date function, wait 30 seconds, and then call the next function (which would be current weather). After all functions have been through the loop, I'd like the loop to go back to the clock and start all over again.

How would I be able to do this?

**Re-edit:** After the suggestion from Chop, I'd like to use something along the lines of the following - while the clock updates every second as planned, the functions don't switch over every 30 seconds.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {      
    function displayOne(){
        displayTime();
        setTimeout(displayTwo, 30000);
    }
    function displayTwo() {
        currentWeather();
        setTimeout(displayOne, 30000);
    }
    displayOne();
    setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You use `setTimeout`, where you want to use `setInterval` and `setInterval` where you want to use `setTimeout`. Also, there is no need to wrap the functions like this. Just use `setInterval(updateTime, 1000)`.

Comment: And perhaps more importantly -- don't define and execute the `displayOne` function at the same time. If you do it like this, the name `displayOne` will only be visible from the inside of the `displayOne` function and not from the outside (you will get `ReferenceError: displayOne is not defined`). Define `displayOne` and then call it. The same thing with `displayTwo`.

Comment: Witiko, how would I go about defining those specific functions before calling them? Could you give me an example please..?

Comment: Instead of `(function displayOne() { ... })()`, first define the function: `function displayOne() { ... }` and then execute it: `displayOne()`. Much like in Chop's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain them like this

```
function callFx(fx) {
    setTimeout(fx, 30000)
}

function function1() { // update weather
    callFx(function2)
}
function function2() { // update time
    callFx(function3)
}
function function3() { // some operation
    callFx(function1)
}
```

Or using setInterval

```
var functions = [function1, function2, function3]
var index = 0

setInterval(function() {
    functions[index]()
    if(!functions[++index]) index = 0
}, 30000)
```

---

The full code would be

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {      
    function displayOne(){
        setTimeout(displayTwo, 30000)
    }
    function displayTwo() {
        currentWeather()
        setTimeout(displayOne, 30000)
    }
    displayOne()
    setInterval(updateTime, 1000)
})
```

Comment: Or `index = (index + 1) % functions.length`, if you like modular arithmetic.

Comment: setInterval is a great idea; but the issue I think I'm facing is `displayTime();` uses setTimeout to update the time every second. Can I have both setInterval and setTimeout operating together I have it simply in the `displayTime();` function as: `setTimeout(function () { displayTime(); }, 1000);`

Comment: Yes, you can combine setTimeout and setInterval without a problem, because each timer operates under separate id. You can find some more info about timers here http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: Just FYI: Should the browser be busy executing other javascript code during the time the `setInterval()` should execute, the browser will miss the tick and will wait for the next 30th second. If you use `setTimeout()` and the browser is busy during the time it should execute the function, it will execute the function at the earliest possible moment. So with `setInterval()`, the timing will always be correct, but the ticks may not execute each time. With `setTimeout()`, you may get minor and cummulative delays, but it will always execute after roughly 30 seconds. Pick your poison.

Comment: `setTimeout(f, timeout)` executes `f` only once, so you need to call the `setTimeout` function again like this: `setTimeout(function f() { ...; setTimeout(f, timeout); }, timeout)` if you wish for it to continue executing. `setInterval(f, interval)` continues executing `f` in the given `interval` forever (well, until you call `clearInterval(f)`).

Comment: @Chop: The omission of semicolons is your choice, of course, but it's good practice to insert them, since most code minification tools are unable to add the semicolons to correct places when removing newlines and will destroy your code.

Comment: @Witiko: A minification tool that changes the semantics of valid programs is a broken tool

Comment: Indeed, your code is completely valid. Just letting you know that it's much less robust against poorly written tools and the removal of newlines to spare you future pain. In the end it's your decision, but I thought it would be fair to inform your decision, because I've been there and it's a major pain to fix the code afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to trigger calling another function that takes care of changing your widget content by calling the right one of your functions depending on the current state of your widget.